# ActiveRecord batch insert (yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, dao, batch-insert

Is it possible to insert multiple rows in one query with Yii's ActiveRecord? Or is this only possible via the lower-level DAO objects?

I have two models
1- Transaction
2-TransactionItems

There are multiple rows(onclick add row) in transaction Items.

I want to store multiple rows of transactionitems in the database.

[Screenshot of Transaction item table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgXTn.png)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `batchInsert()` method of `yii\db\Command`. See details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert%28%29-detail).
When using it with `ActiveRecord` make sure validate all data before inserting.

Assuming you have array of $models with class `Post`, it can be done like this:

```
$rows = [];
foreach ($models as $model) {
    if (!$model->validate()) {
        // At least one model has invalid data

        break;
    }

    $rows[] = $model->attributes;
}
```

If models don't require validation you can short the code above using `ArrayHelper` for building `$rows` array.

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$rows = ArrayHelper::getColumn($models, 'attributes');
```

Then simply execute batch insert:

```
$postModel = new Post;

Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert(Post::tableName(), $postModel->attributes(), $rows)->execute();
```

P.S. The `$postModel` just used for pulling attirubute names list, you can also pull this from any existing $model in your $models array.

If you don't need to insert all attributes you can specify it when filling `$rows` array:

```
$rows[] = [
    'title' => $model->title,
    'content' => $model->content,
];
```

Don't forget to replace `$postModel->attributes` to `['title', 'content']`.

In case of larger amount of attributes you can use some array functions to specify exact attributes for inserting.

Comment: So, the answer is no? I should use DAO.

Comment: I think currently the ActiveRecord does not support this out of the box. You can do some further research, but I can't find it.

Comment: $postModel->attributes should be $postModel->attributes()

Comment: @Dodo Thanks for remark, corrected the answer.

Comment: @arogachev: how can get all laster insert id in batch insert ?

Comment: Extended version of this approach (that supports `beforeSave` and `afterSave` events) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39601194/3793592

Comment: works well; you must consider that it gives sql error if data array happens to be empty

Comment: is the custom `behaviors()` on that `Post` model stil working? In my case it didn't.

Comment: what if I want to skip any column from `$rows`?